# Creating an online whiteboard app using websockets & HTML5?

Tags: jquery, html, websocket, whiteboard

I plan to use HTML5, php, websockets, jQuery & MySql as backend (if saving, etc is required).
However, I have no prior experience in websockets.
This is an example I found: 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WebSocketWhiteBoard.aspx
However they are taking websockets from localserver. I wish to use the websocket API provided. 
http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/
We need to begin with a handshake between the client & server. Can you help me as to how I can do so?
Thanks!

Comment: http://github.com/katspaugh/whiteboard

Answer (score 2):

You could look at [PHP WebSocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/), [apache-websocket/`mod_websocket`](https://github.com/disconnect/apache-websocket), you could use a separate [self hosted realtime web solution](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide#self-hosted) or look at a [hosted realtime service](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide#hosted-services) such as [Pusher](http://pusher.com) (who I work for).

There are a number of similar questions about using WebSockets, PHP and related technologies which I recommend you take a look at:

- [HTML 5 Web Sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359691/html-5-web-sockets)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262543/what-are-good-resources-for-learning-html-5-websockets
- [websockets apache server compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804313/websockets-apache-server-compatibility/8809793#8809793)
- [How to Use Long Polling or Ajax Push in your Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534706/how-to-use-long-polling-or-ajax-push-in-your-website/8536618#8536618)

Comment: Pusher sounds really good. But, I'm just a beginner & doing this project in university. Could you please elaborate/explain/give me any ideas or resources as to how I can use pusher to fulfill my purpose. And as to whether there could be any limitations? Thanks!

Comment: @PrernaChikersal I don't want to turn this into a Pusher specific question but the [quickstart guide](http://pusher.com/docs/quickstart) and [tutorials](http://pusher.com/tutorials) is a good starting point. If you've Pusher-related questions you should probably go through [Pusher Support](http://pusher.com/support). You can find a [getting started with WebSockets resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988133/getting-started-with-web-sockets) here on StackOverflow as a general good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using something like `node.js` as your web server (and as you're planning to use PHP I presume that's not the case) you actually need a *separate* WebSocket server too.

If you're running on your own hardware that should be fine, but you're unlikely to find a standard ISP web-host offering you the ability to run your own servers daemons.

There are a number of WebSocket servers and/or libraries available that perform the WebSocket protocol handshake.  I've used one that was written for `node.js` but unfortunately the WS specification was still going through some changes and it's no longer compatible with Chrome.

Also, don't get confused by `Socket.IO` which many people refer to as "WebSockets" - it's not - it's a more general communications method that looks a bit like WebSockets, and may use real WebSockets as its transport layer, but is actually a different protocol altogether.

Comment: Our website is hosted on host4post.com. I don't know anything about node.js. Can you please elaborate? Thanks a lot!

Comment: webhosts operate server software such as "apache" as a managed service.  "node.js" (or any other software that can act as a WebSocket server) is not typically offered like that.

Comment: Thanks. Lets say if I don't use websockets. Is there some other way to implement the same application?